# How do I launch application one from another in C#?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, launch

I have two desktop applications. After closing the first application, the first application will start the second application.

How do I start the second application after finishing first application?

My first application creates a separate desktop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use .NET's Process Class to start a process as other people described. Then the question is when to call.

In most cases, using either `Form.Closing` or `Form.Closed` event seems to be an easy choice.

However, if someone else can handle the event and can set `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to true, this may not be the right place to do this.  Also, `Form.Closing` and `Form.Closed` events will not be raised when  `Application.Exit()` is called.  I am not sure whether either of events will be raised if any unhandled exceptions occur. (Also, you have to decide whether you want to launch the second application in case of `Application.Exit()` or any unhandled exception).

If you really want to make sure the second application (App2) launches after the first application (App1) exited, you can play a trick:

1. Create a separate application (App0)
2. App0 launches App1
3. App0 waits for App1 to exit with Process.WaitExit()
4. App0 launches App2 and exits itself

The sample console app attached below shows a very simple case: my sample app launches the notepad first. Then, when the notepad exits, it launches mspaint and exits itself.

If you want to hide the console, you can simply set the 'Output Type' property from 'Console Application' to 'Windows Application' under 'Application' tab of Project Property.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessExitSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                Process firstProc = new Process();
                firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
                firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                firstProc.Start();

                firstProc.WaitForExit();

                //You may want to perform different actions depending on the exit code.
                Console.WriteLine("First process exited: " + firstProc.ExitCode);

                Process secondProc = new Process();
                secondProc.StartInfo.FileName = "mspaint.exe";
                secondProc.Start();                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred!!!: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) when you are exiting your first application.

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName   = "notepad.exe";  // just for example, you can use yours.
p.Start();
```

Comment: in which event i have to start second application, whether it is form closing or form closed(first application)

Comment: It doesn't matter (unless you cancel the close in `Closing`), since process is launched asynchronously, and it won't prevent your application from continuing to do whatever it is supposed to do - including shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

You could just shell off to it, so when you are about to exit the first app just start the second app via:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"PATH\NAME.EXE");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET's [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code:

```
try
{
  stateMainLayout b = new stateMainLayout();
 b.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
 b.ShowDialog();
 }
catch
{
 stateMainLayout b = new stateMainLayout();
b.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSharp/PowerShell Calling Another Program and Send/Recieve Data:
https://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/sending-input-from-csharppowershell-to-another-program/

Answer (score 0):

in Some cases its necessary to add  **Working directory**
 to your code in order to make the app works perfectly. especially when the app has dependency to DLL and other resources.

```
 TestProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"; 
 TestProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\blah\blah\Directory of notepad.exe\";
 TestProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ProcName means the name of the application you want to start 
but it can only start system application and some other application

```
        public void Startapp(String ProcName)
        {
            try
            {
                Process firstProc = new Process();
                firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = ProcName;
                firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                firstProc.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer?