# How Run Unity3D game from another programm (Mac/Windows)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want create Client application and user will can open Games only from Client application.
How i can do that?
How i can check in Unity3d game - that user try run the game from client application?
And i need send some properties.

Comment: Main lang for game - C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I launch application one from another in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112981/how-do-i-launch-application-one-from-another-in-c)

Comment: @OMGtechy It isn't a duplicate it doesn't work same way in unity.

Comment: @DavidAbaev What are you righting the client with unity or another form?

Comment: @ZoomVirus -- For Windows i write WPF, for Mac right now i dont write. And my main question - it is - How check in Unity If I run game from application? And when I run i need to send some properies from WPF. so i need check in unity if i got properties, check them and ONLY AFTER it - RUN game. Thnak you

Comment: @davidAbaev You could use the data file approach with a mutex where you use a mutex to make sure the program cannot be ran more than once and when the game is ran if it is ran from a wpf then create a file to read from then if that file exists change a value to make sure it knows to check for another file with updated values when the program has got values from data files delete them. that is the most basic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a launher application for your game.and then from your launcher application you should launch the actual game application and you should use some command lone arguments  or you can even use some random hash number generated in launcher application and then update this random hash in db for this session and then launch the game by sending this hash no through command line parameters and the game will send the hash it gets from command line to web server and the server will tey to match up the game clients number with the launcher's hash no. if both matches then the api will send a success status to the game client. this way you can make it very secure so the game client will only work if it was launched by the launcher.