# Is there any simple C# code example to invoke Main() with public modifier from outside?

Tags: c#

Quoted from [this site (click)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx):

> Main is declared inside a class or struct. Main must be static and it *should not be public*.

It means that the Main method can be public.

Now consider the following 2 projects:

## Project 1: HelloWorld

```
using static System.Console;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

I assign `public` modifier to the Main.
Then I compile it to produce an application named `HelloWorld.exe`.

## Project 2: Invoker

```
namespace Invoker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // I want to invoke Main in HelloWorld.exe here.
            // How to do it?
        }
    }
}
```

This project tries to invoke `Main` defined in `HelloWorld.exe`

## Question

Without using `Process`, how can the `Invoker.exe` call public `Main` defined in `HelloWorld.exe`? This question is used to find an example to invoke public Main from outside. That is why I don't want to use `Process`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between public static void Main() and private static void Main() in a C# console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871104/what-is-the-difference-between-public-static-void-main-and-private-static-void)

Comment: This question's unclear. Are you asking simply if such an example exists? Or are you asking for a specific example for your own use? Calling a `public static void Main()` method in your `Program` class is no different than calling any other public, static method: add a reference to your assembly (if using from a different one), and then call it as e.g. `Program.Main();` (or if you have `string[] args`, passing an appropriate value of course). The proposed duplicate doesn't actually include any useful code examples, so it doesn't seem to address the question you are asking, whatever that is.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly("HelloWorld.exe")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main** should not be public since it is not supposed to be called by any other methods in your assemblies. It is only the CLR that should be able to call it when the application starts. The access specifiers does not apply to the CLR in the same way (if at all) as to your assemblies that are managed by the CLR.

If you want it to be public; but that would mean any other application could reference it without reflection.

That's what the runtime does; just start looking for static methods named "Main" with various signatures and then invokes the first one it finds.  Likely something like this:

```
foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    foreach(MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (methodInfo.Name == "Main" /*TODO: && methodInfo.Parameters is valid*/)
        {
            methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly revisit my question and update your answer to conform to my question?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112981/how-do-i-launch-application-one-from-another-in-c)

Comment: No. I don't want to use Process.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian Instead of `.exe` of hello world..  cant you compile it to `dll` and use it?

Comment: I think I have to keep HelloWorld.exe as is.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian  for that You need to make a class library and not a Console Application. The console application is translated into an .exe whereas the class library will then be compiled into a dll which you can reference in your windows project.

`Right click on your Console Application (here hello world)-> Properties -> Change the Output type to Class Library`

Comment: I will not make it as a class library because it will not reflect my objective.

Comment: then last approach in my bag is  [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: So public Main in HelloWord.exe cannot be called from outside? Then what is the purpose of public in Main explained in MSDN?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93253/discussion-between-webruster-and-yasashii-eirian).

Comment: @YasashiiEirian If you WANT, if you are  marking it as public, means ex: you are turning a console app into an API.and  The entry point of a program is marked with the`.entrypoint` IL directive. It does not matter if the method or the class is public or not, all that matters is this directive.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian this is what i conclude 1)**Public**-If we want to initiate entry point by any external program,then you might need to make it public so it is accessible. 2)**Private**-If we know there is no external usage for the application then it is better to make it private so no external application access it. (Here when you make public using of Process can be able to acess it)

Comment: `Process` can access regardless of either `public` or `private`, is it right?

Comment: Yes you can start any process with `.exe` using process